# How to get the "started typing" of telethon?

Tags: telethon

I tried it:

```
@client.on(events.UserUpdate())
async def handler(event):
    print(event)
```

But I only get UpdateUserStatus.

events.Raw does not give the right results either

Comment: If Telegram does not send the update, Telethon won't dispatch any event. If you tried `events.Raw` and saw nothing, Telegram is probably not sending the update.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using this method? This could get status of user typing iirc

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.chataction.ChatAction

Comment: This method is for updates in chats. This is not what I need((